# access child $this from parent::__construct

Tags: php

I have two classes

```
class one {

    public function __construct() {
        //I need $this to be instance of child class
        $child_this = $this;
    }

}

class two extends one {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

where I need to access the child $this inside the parent constructor  Without passing the child instance as a parameter, thanks

Comment: In order to use parent $this, you need to create one with `new one`, there's no other way.

Comment: well, guess I need to pass the instance to parent::__construct thanks for your help

Comment: This is like naming a child before he/she has been born!

Comment: instantiating a child in a parent class is possible but not a well constructed design pattern. basic of Inheritance is child inherits parent not the other way

Comment: @user1205600 Can I somehow improve my answer for you?

Answer (score 0):

It is a totally bad idea. You are coupling your child to your parent (since it's its child) and also coupling your parent (that should actually never know anything about its children) to an implementation of its child, aka Circular Dependency. And no, it will not work out of the box in any language. The only way to achieve this is to pass the child's instance to the parent's constructor (black magic, don't do this). By doing so you'll also break [liskov substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), since the signature of your child is smaller then the signature of its parent.

The only reasonable way I can think of that you may want to access your child's context from within the parent is to get the it's class name. You can use the [get_class()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) function to achieve this.